# Como mostrar ultimo registro por fecha y hora final php, mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una serie de registros que se relacionan por medio de una referencia.

Lo que estoy buscando hacer es que me muestre solo el registro con la fecha y hora más reciente, ejemplo:

tengo los siguientes registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El registro con la fecha y hora más reciente seria el del id 405 dice que la fechafin fue del 28/07/2020 y la horafinal fue a la 1:47 de la tarde.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$desbloq="select * from p_atendidas where refe='$pro' ORDER BY fechafin,horafinal DESC LIMIT 1";
$okdesblo=mysqli_query($con,$desbloq);
$posdesbl=mysqli_fetch_assoc($okdesblo);
```

Pero esta mal porque me trae es otro registro que no es.

De que forma podria arreglar la consulta para que traiga el valor con fecha y hora mas reciente.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es horafinal?

Comment: Es varchar 256 caracteres

Comment: Entiendo, quizá por eso no funciona el ejemplo que te brindaron antes, voy a publicar una respuesta y luego me dices si te funciona.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. @JosueArriola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu mejor opción es concatenar la `fechafin` y la `horafinal` para obtener el valor de la máxima fecha y hora insertada en la DB, ya que se me ocurre que si lo haces independiente podrías toparte con un error en el que haya una fecha `fechafin` máxima pero la `horafinal` máxima no corresponda a la fecha, dicho eso, podrías intentar esto, luego de concatenar la fecha y la hora, usar la función `STR_TO_DATE` para hacer la conversión de los campos de texto hacia fechas y horas validas para la MySQL y así realizar la comparación:

```
SELECT * FROM tuTabla  
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fechafin,' ',horafinal),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fechafin,' ',horafinal),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')) from tuTabla);
```

Comment: Hola, aun no logro resolver el problema, esta consulta no me trae ningun registro, debe ser que tengo algo mal, pero mi consulta esta tal cual como la tienes alli en el ajemplo solo que le agrego la refe para que me traiga los registros de una referencia en especifico. muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor detalla el error que estas teniendo y como estas realizando la consulta, imagino que cambiaste la parte de `tuTabla` por el nombre real de la tabla. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

A través de 2 subconsultas:

- Una que evalúe donde la fechafin sea igual a la fecha máxima registrada en dicha columna
- Otra que evalúe donde la horafin sea igual a la hora máxima registrada en esa columna

Quedando así:

```
SELECT * FROM tuTabla 
WHERE fechafin = (SELECT MAX(fechafin) from tuTabla)
AND horafinal = (SELECT MAX(horafin) from tu tabla);
```

Ambas consultas nos devolverán una sola fila para cada caso, el valor máximo en cada escenario y con eso podemos componer el filtro indicando con el operador `AND` que haga la selección donde ambos valores sean los máximos registrados.

Comment: excelente tu respuesta la aplique de esta forma pero no trae ningun registro en el phpmyadmin: SELECT * FROM p_atendidas WHERE refe='955881' AND fechafin = (SELECT MAX(fechafin) from p_atendidas) AND horafinal = (SELECT MAX(horafinal) from p_atendidas)

Comment: Si no te trae valores es por que alguna de las condiciones dadas no se esta cumpliendo, recuerda estás usando el operador AND y eso implica cierta restricción en las reglas a cumplir

Comment: Esta como raro, no funciono, mejor dicho no me trae nigun registros asi lo haga solo con la horafinal, de todas formas seguire buscando a ver que puede ser el problema, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @BetaM